# Do_ssh failing in initial setup

Tags: setup, ssh

I set up my Pi, and I get output to a screen / keyboard working etc.

However, when I run `raspi-config`, and pick the SSH option I get

> Initial ssh key generation still running. Please wait and try again.

I left the Pi on for a few hours but this didn't help.

I tried bashing on the keyboard for a while as I assume this is due to insufficient entropy.

Is there a way to fix this??

Comment: Can you just generate the keys manually?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The advice in the Raspberry Pi [forum thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=11935) (`rm /var/log/regen_ssh_keys.log`) got the raspi-config to make it look like it had worked, but the host keys weren't generated.  I fixed this by doing

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host*
sudo ssh-keygen -A
```

the `rm` was needed as otherwise `ssh-keygen` was seeing the 0 length files as valid keys

If this doesn't work, try removing the log file:

```
rm /var/log/regen_ssh_keys.log
```

Comment: I have tried this multiple times, including reboots with no luck.

Advanced > ssh still says 'Initial ssh key generation still running. Please wait and try again.' 

Also, after that message I get 'There was an error running option A4 SSH' 

I am running the Raspbian 2015-02-16 image

Comment: I wiped the SD card and imaged it again with Raspbian. This time I made the ssh change on the initial boot up. Odd, annoying, but working now.

Comment: Removing the log file `rm /var/log/regen_ssh_keys.log` is the keystep. If you remove it and then follow the steps you will be able to setup the ssh again.